How to install Ubuntu 22.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso unattended
Basically, when I insert my USB with the Ubuntu iso, it will automatically install Ubuntu offline. It will automatically select the language, erase disk and install Ubuntu, create user, select the region, etc. It will work exactly like autounattend.xml for Windows 11. I am only using it for Desktop/Laptop, no servers or VM ware. What I found most similar is this How do I create a completely unattended install of Ubuntu?, but it seems a bit outdated, and I can't get it to work. Does anyone know any alternative solutions?

Why would it be outdated??  You're asking about the last supported release that is using the now deprecated ubiquity installer?   Later releases use different installers thus differ.  Preseeds for ubiquity match the debian installer which is no longer used.

This question is similar to: How do I create a completely unattended install of Ubuntu?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
